Size doesn't change when using .css()
I'm trying to make a dynamic element using jQuery, CSS and HTML. When I click on it, the function to resize the element gets executed and works properly, also revealing the "close" icon.
But when I click on the close icon, the function to close the panel gets correctly executed BUT the element won't resize.
I already tried putting the jQuery property as !important but no luck.
Click on the box saying "Impostazioni", then on the "missing image" icon).


function openSettings() {
  $("#settings").css("height", "40vh");
  $("#settings").css("width", "30vw");
  $("#settings").css("margin-top", "2vh");
  $("#settings-container").css("cursor", "auto");
  $("#settings-container").attr("pointer-events", "none");
  $("#settings").css("opacity", "1");
  $(".close").css("opacity", "0.8");
}

function closeSettings() {
  alert("clicked!");
  $("#settings").css("height", "0");
  $("#settings").css("width", "0");
  $("#settings").css("margin-top", "0");
  $("#settings-container").css("cursor", "pointer");
  $("#settings-container").attr("pointer-events", "auto");
  $("#settings").css("opacity", "0");
  $(".close").css("opacity", "0");
}
.impostazioni {
  position: fixed;
  top: 2vh;
  right: 2vw;
  border: 1px solid #525252;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #9292924f;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 0.6vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.impostazioni:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #6969699a;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.impostazioni p {
  margin: 0 auto auto 0;
}

.settings-inner {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  word-break: keep-all;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow: visible;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1vh;
  right: 1vh;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="impostazioni" type="button" onclick="openSettings()" id="settings-container">
  <img src="close.png" onclick="closeSettings()" class="close">
  <div>
    <p>IMPOSTAZIONI</p>
    <div class="settings-inner" id="settings">
      <div class="cell-filter">
        <span class="cell-filter-title">Numero azienda</span>
        <input type="text" class="cell-filter-input" value="" id="numero-azienda">
      </div>
      <div class="cell-filter">
        <span class="cell-filter-title">Porto assegnato</span>
        <input type="text" class="cell-filter-input" value="" id="porto-azienda">
      </div>
      <div class="cell-filter">
        <span class="cell-filter-title">Compilatore</span>
        <input type="text" class="cell-filter-input" value="" id="compilatore-azienda">
      </div>
      <input class="salva" type="button" value="SALVA" onclick="saveSettings()" disabled="true">
    </div>
  </div>



JSFiddle

Your "open" function is on a parent of the "close" function, your event will bubble and trigger the open immediately after any close event.

There's probably a duplicate I haven't found yet, but I suspect you're looking for event.stopPropagation() on the "close" button.  Basically, it is re-styling the elements as expected, but when the click event bubbles up to the parent it invokes openSettings() again.

Thank you so much guys! Would've never made it without you. Thanks.

Don't have inline event handling $('.impostazioni').on('click', () => { $("#settings").css({ height: "40vh", width: "30vw", marginTop: "2vh", opacity: "1", }); $("#settings-container").css("cursor", "auto").attr("pointer-events", "none"); $(".close").css("opacity", "0.8"); }); $(".close").on('click', (event) => { event.stopPropagation(); $("#settings").css({ height: "0", width: "0", marginTop: "0", opacity: "0", }); $("#settings-container").css("cursor", "pointer").attr("pointer-events", "auto"); $(".close").css("opacity", "0"); });
